# Difference between vistime plotly version and highchart version

Tags: r, highcharts, plotly, vistime

The following data plots correctly for `plotly` engine, but plots data wrongly when using `highchart` engine. Both done with `r` library `vistime`.

```
library(vistime)

vistime(yf, col.event = "ns", col.start = "tstart", col.end = "tend",title = "End of Era (UTC times)",col.group = "ns", show_labels = FALSE)
hc_vistime(yf, col.event = "ns", col.start = "tstart", col.end = "tend",title = "End of Era (UTC times)",col.group = "ns", col.color = rep(c('#020202'),15), show_labels = FALSE)

yf = structure(list(tstart = structure(c(1596215940, 1596216360, 1596216840,1596218580, 1596220920, 1596221460, 1596222060, 1596227460, 1596228720,1596230580, 1596232620, 1596232920, 1596233340, 1596235500, 1596236460), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tend = structure(c(1596216240,1596216840, 1596218580, 1596220920, 1596221460, 1596222060, 1596226680,1596228720, 1596230580, 1596232620, 1596232920, 1596233340, 1596235500,1596236460, 1596237420), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),ns = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C","D", "E", "A", "F", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:15)
```

[image: Plotly result]
Plotly has correct y-axis labels

[image: highchart result]
Highchart plot gets the y-axis wrongly ordered, in reverse order of that of correct labels

Any pointers to fix this is welcome. Also can the fill colors be a single color, for each group? Currently each point for each group gets different colors.

TIA

Comment: What exactly do you mean that this data is displayed incorrectly?
How should it work for you?

Comment: @madepiet I've added the code output for comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with vistime but it seems that the data mapping in this wrapper is interpreted the other way around for highcharts. Wrappers or libraries get the data and have to map it and connect it so that it works the same for what we want to visualize. I think it is best to contact the authors of this wrapper and get support from them.